# How to learn whether an interface is derived from a specific interface?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an interface like that:

```
 public interface IViewA : IViewB, IViewC
 {
    byte prop { get; set; }
 }
```

and I have a generic method like that:

```
public void OpenPopup<T>(WindowState state)
{
    if ((typeof(T) as IViewC)!=null)
    {
         //Process A
    }
    else
    {
        //Process B
    }
```

}

Although I send T as an interface which derives from IViewC, Process A is not being processed.

So how to learn at runtime via reflection whether an interface derives from other interface?

thanks

Comment: `typeof(t)` will always be a System.Type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
if ( typeof(IViewC).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)) { 
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `typeof` use `isAssignableFrom`.

Comment: Please show sample code.  I'm asking because I would think the answer needs both.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like `typeof(IViewC).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))`.

Right now you're trying to treat `typeof(T)`, which is a `System.Type` as `IViewC`, which will not work.

Answer (score 1):

`typeof(T) as IViewC` is completely wrong. You are trying to cast from `Type` to `IViewC`, which will always fail, always resulting in null.

You want `typeof(T).GetInterfaces()`, and look through the returned list to see if your interface is in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((typeof(T) as IViewC)!=null)
```

This is wrong. What you wrote tests whether the `Type` object returned by `typeof(T)` is an `IViewC`, which it obviously isn't.

You want:

```
if (typeof(IViewC).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
```

Comment: I believe this is wrong as well.  The "is" operator in C# can only be used on reference values.  T is a generic type parameter.